# Experience Cloud - Missing Fields on Contact Support Form

Tags: experience-cloud

I've added the Contact Support Form to an Experience Cloud page in order to allow an authenticated user to create a case, however, the rendered form does not display any of the fields. It's missing the Subject and Discussion fields, which are the only two fields that should be being displayed on the form.

As far as I can tell, the component has the correct setup data. It has a Global Action assigned to Authenticated User and no global action for Public Access - I've also validated that the Global Action works and that the logged in users profiles have access to the fields that are on the Global Action (Subject, Description).

For reference, the Global Action is creating a Case with a specific Record Type, offering Subject and Description for the user to fill in and then auto-filling Case Origin and Status.

I've also got the Automated Case User set to a user with a System Administrator profile as this implies this can be an issue with field visibility/permissions based on [this Salesforce Help Article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000351956&type=1).

Does anyone have any ideas why the fields aren't showing up?

[image: Contact Support Form]